# Repeating content in CKeditor

Tags: repeat

When I put hyperlink on any word in ckeditor4, it starts repeat at top of the article from that word to end word of the article ,tell what may be the reason behind it and how to remove it

I am expecting good answer so that I can solve the query as soon as possible regarding it